# Add WHERE in SELECT-line for trigger that contains JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a trigger that grabs information from multiple tables and
calculates an "orderTotal".

My trigger does calculate the correct orderTotal, but it updates orderTotal for all rows in "RestaurantOrder" with the latest value. I only want it to update the row with the corresponding orderID.

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER totalFeeOrder
   ON orderDetails
   AFTER INSERT
   AS
   BEGIN
           IF EXISTS (SELECT orderID FROM INSERTED)
           BEGIN
                UPDATE RestaurantOrder 
                SET orderTotal = 
                (SELECT (RO.orderDeliveryFee+SUM(OD.itemQuantity*i.itemPrice)) FROM orderDetails as OD
                JOIN Item as I on I.itemID = OD.itemID
                JOIN RestaurantOrder as RO on RO.orderID = OD.orderID
                WHERE RO.orderID in (SELECT orderID from INSERTED)
                and OD.orderID in (SELECT orderID From INSERTED)
                GROUP BY RO.orderID, RO.orderDeliveryFee)
           END
   END;
```

I tried adding a WHERE clause after the SELECT and before the JOIN to specify that it's only for the INSERTED orderID, but
it doesn't allow me to.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following is what you require (untested of course).

You don't need the initial *exists* - rows are only updated for successful joins. You don't need to join back to the *OrderDetails* table since all the inserted rows exist in the *inserted* table.

```
with t as (
    select i.orderID, Sum(i.itemQuantity * it.itemPrice) tot
    from inserted i
    join item it on it.itemId = i.itemId
    group by i.orderID
)
update ro set ro.OrderTotal = ro.OrderDeliveryFee + t.tot
from t
join RestaurantOrder ro on ro.orderID = t.orderID
```

Edit - in case you have multiple existing rows per OrderID you can include in the expression like so

```
with t as (
    select od.orderID, Sum(od.itemQuantity * it.itemPrice) tot
    from (select distinct OrderId from inserted) i
    join OrderDetails od on od.orderID = i.orderID
    join item it on it.itemId = od.itemId
    group by od.orderID
)
update ro set ro.OrderTotal = ro.OrderDeliveryFee + t.tot
from t
join RestaurantOrder ro on ro.orderID = t.orderID
```

Comment: If a pair of rows  is added to a set of existing ones for the order I guess OP wants the sum of all  order related rows not only just inserted.

Comment: Thanks Stu! I have omitted necessary information. 

I'm creating a simple food delivery database with multiple restaurants.

The table "Item" contains items from different restaurants with the column "itemPrice" Then I have the table called "orderDetails" which has two columns "orderID" and "itemID".

When a customer places an order, the orderID is generated through the table "RestaurantOrder". The items that the customer ordered is saved in orderDetails matched with orderID.

Regarding updated prices - it shouldn't affect the ordertotals for old orders.

Comment: Have added an edit above that *does* include existing rows for an orderID. Hopefully it's enough to put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks so much Stu, and thanks Serg for helping out with the clarification. I'll try it out. Appreciate y'alls time

Comment: @Serg I have edited and added additional version that does include all rows from the base table based on the OrderID (I assume that's correct as it's what the OP was doing).

Comment: @Serg This may be too advanced for me but the updated code is calculating all the orderTotal correctly when the trigger is activated

Comment: No it joins based on the *distinct* list of ID values - that's 1:1 to the base table, sums and groups by the OrderId, that *should* be correct.

Comment: Distinct will do the trick, correct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using another column and a trigger, I recommend you keep you database properly normalized by instead using an ***indexed view***. This is a view that the server will materialize to disk, and will maintain along with normal indexes on every update to the base tables.

Unfortunately, there are a number of restrictions on them, primarily:

- It must be schema-bound.
- Only `INNER JOIN` is allowed.
- For a grouped view, you must include `COUNT_BIG(*)` and the only other aggregate allowed is `SUM`
- I recommend always using `WITH (NOEXPAND)` when querying the indexed view, for performance reasons.
- You cannot have calculated columns with the `SUM`, so to create the full total you will need a second non-indexed view that references the first. This also has the benefit of enforcing the `NOEXPAND` hint.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.vRestaurantOrder_Indexed
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

SELECT
  RO.orderID,
  RO.orderDeliveryFee,
  SubTotal = SUM(OD.itemQuantity * I.itemPrice),
  ItemCount = COUNT_BIG(*)  -- must have count in a grouped view
FROM dbo.OrderDetails as OD
JOIN dbo.Item as I on I.itemID = OD.itemID
JOIN dbo.RestaurantOrder as RO on RO.orderID = OD.orderID
GROUP BY
  RO.orderID,
  RO.orderDeliveryFee;
```

Then you can create an index on it

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX vRestaurantOrder_Indexed_CX
  ON dbo.vRestaurantOrder_Indexed (orderID);
```

Then the secondary view:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.vRestaurantOrder
AS
SELECT
  RO.orderID,
  RO.orderDeliveryFee,
  RO.SubTotal,
  RO.ItemCount,
  orderTotal = RO.orderDeliveryFee + RO.SubTotal
FROM dbo.vRestaurantOrder_Indexed AS RO WITH (NOEXPAND);
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look this through and keep it in mind