# SQL Trigger Doubling Summary Amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Building a shopping cart, of sorts.

Two tables, `Cart` and `CartLine` linked with `CartID` field.  I need an sql trigger to update the total fields in the `Cart` table when a `CartLine` record is added, updated, deleted.  My code is below.  It seems to double my amounts when an update/etc. occurs.

Code:
'

```
--Update cart totals.
begin
with cte2 as (
    select
      c.CartID,
      isnull(sum(cl.GoodsTotal), 0) [TotalGoods],
      isnull(sum(cl.LineTotal), 0) [TotalPrice],
      isnull(sum(cl.TaxTotal), 0) [TotalTax],
      (isnull(sum(cl.LineTotal), 0) + isnull(sum(cl.TaxTotal), 0)) [TotalTotal]

    from tblCartLine cl with (nolock)
    join inserted i with (nolock) on cl.CartID = i.CartID
    inner join tblCart c with (nolock) on i.CartID = c.CartID
    where isnull(cl.Deleted, 0) = 0
    group by c.CartID
)
    
update tblCart
set
  TotalCost = cte2.TotalGoods,
  TotalPrice = cte2.TotalPrice,
  TotalTax = cte2.TotalTax,
  TotalTotal = cte2.TotalTotal
                    
from tblCart c
inner join cte2 on c.CartID = cte2.CartID
where c.CartID = cte2.CartID
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc232c4099a9ba5aa5a9e4e75afe6468)

Comment: What table is the trigger attached to? What is doubling?

Comment: What do you think all those `nolock` hints can possibly do for you _during an update inside a trigger_?

Comment: The trigger is tied to tblCartLine as an after update, delete, insert.  The nolock code is there because i copied and pasted from one set of code to another...lazy, I know.

All of the dollar values that are being updated are doubling (TotalCost, TotalPrice, TotalTax, etc.)

Comment: Post ALL of the trigger code - beginning with "create trigger ...". And then FORMAT all that code to make it readable. Cramming everything together with no white space and no indentation is just a bad sign. I also suggest you focus on a single action - INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE - so you can concentrate on a subset of the logic you will eventually need. To really understand your code requires knowledge of your schema - so include DDL for the tables involved.

Comment: In your fiddle, I'm unclear the point of updating the line totals, it seems those should be computed columns instead. Also you don't take into account the `deleted` table, and you could even just do this with an indexed view instead of triggers. Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71416097/14868997

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your schema, I see a huge bunch of issues. In no particular order:

- Most columns are `NULL`able. Why? What would it mean if a `Cart` had no `DateTimeCreated`, why would there ever be such a row? What about `Deleted`, is there a third indeterminate state (quantum mechanics?) which is neither deleted nor not-deleted?
- Use of `money` data type, which has serious rounding issues. Use `decimal` instead, to an appropriate precision and scale.
- Using `tbl` prefix is annoying, everyone knows they are tables anyway.
- Your existing trigger code also has problems. There is an absolute lack of proper formatting, making it unreadable. Whitespace is free, you know.
- You are not checking the `deleted` virtual table in the case of updates and deletes. You need to join it by primary key.
- There is no need to re-join the table multiple times, you can just use `inserted` and `deleted` and subtract the difference.
- `NOLOCK` is the wrong thing to do. If you are worried about locking then you should probably be using `SNAPSHOT` isolation, and if you are worried about performance you can use `WITH (TABLOCK)` for the same benefits.
- There seems to be no need for the trigger to modify `CartLine`, you can just use computed columns:

  ```sql
  ALTER TABLE tblCartLine
      ADD ExtCost AS (Quantity * Cost);
  ALTER TABLE tblCartLine
      ADD TaxTotal AS (Quantity * Price) * (TaxRate / 100.0);
  ALTER TABLE tblCartLine
      ADD LineTotal AS (Quantity * i.Price);
  ```

And then your trigger should look like this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UtblCartLine] 
   ON  [dbo].[tblCartLine] 
   AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL(@@PROCID, 'AFTER', 'DML') > 0
    RETURN;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    RETURN;

UPDATE tblCart
SET
  TotalCost  += i.DiffGoods,
  TotalPrice += i.DiffPrice,
  TotalTax   += i.DiffTax,
  TotalTotal += i.DiffTotal
FROM tblCart c
JOIN (
    SELECT
      ISNULL(i.CartID, d.CartID) CartID,
      ISNULL(SUM(i.GoodsTotal), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(d.GoodsTotal), 0) DiffGoods,
      ISNULL(SUM(i.LineTotal), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(d.LineTotal), 0) DiffPrice,
      ISNULL(SUM(i.TaxTotal), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(d.TaxTotal), 0) DiffTax,
      ISNULL(SUM(i.LineTotal + i.TaxTotal), 0) - ISNULL(SUM(d.LineTotal + d.TaxTotal), 0) DiffTotal
    FROM inserted i
    FULL JOIN deleted d ON d.CartLineID = i.CartLineID
    GROUP BY
      ISNULL(i.CartID, d.CartID)
) i ON i.CartID = c.CartID;
```

Adding in `Deleted = 0` requires conditional aggregation to do correctly.

---

**However, I recommend you don't use triggers at all.**

Instead use a view. If needed for performance, you can use an *indexed view*. The server can maintain an index on the view in line with any updates/inserts and effectively do all the above code automatically.

Indexed views have some restrictions. In particular:

- Must be schema-bound, so you can't change underlying columns without dropping the view.
- Only inner joins.
- No subqueries or derived tables.
- Aggregation is allowed, but you must have a `COUNT_BIG(*)` column, and the only other aggregation allowed is `SUM`.

```sql
CREATE VIEW CartTotal
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

SELECT
  cl.CartID,
  COUNT_BIG(*) NumberOfLines,
  SUM(cl.GoodsTotal) TotalGoods,
  SUM(cl.LineTotal) TotalPrice,
  SUM(cl.TaxTotal) TotalTax,
  SUM(cl.LineTotal + cl.TaxTotal) TotalTotal
FROM tblCartLine cl
WHERE cl.Deleted = 0
GROUP BY
  cl.CartID;

go
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_CartTotal ON CartTotal (CartID);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Charlieface, for taking the time to actually look through the code.  I am not a lifelong database admin, and there is plenty I do not know about SQL.  You've certainly pointed out a few good tips for changes I should make going forward.  Your commentary also helped me come up with what I believe will be an answer to the issues I've been seeing.  Again, thank you for the time you invested and the assistance.

Comment: Basic formatting is a must, and is not something that is even coding related, just common sense and decency to the next person who reads it (which might be you).